# I can't Read from FileText C#

Tags: c#, oop, generic-list

I have to make a connection between Students,classes, and year like this: One year can have 1 or more classes and 1 class can have 1 or more students.

I made this with a generic list. The problem is that I have to get the information from one `.txt` file and I don't know how to do it.

**My file is like this:**

```
(Year,Class,Name,Surname,Average).
1   314 George      Andrew  8
2   324 Popescu     Andrei  9
2   323 Andreescu   Bogdan  10
3   332 Marin       Darius  9
3   332 Constantin  Roxana  10
```

Code:

```
  public class Student
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public int Average { get; set; }
    }
}


    public class Grupa
    { 
        public int Name { get; set; }
        public List<Student> SetStudent { get; set; }

        public Grupa()
        {
            SetStudent = new List<Student>();
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Grupa: " + this.Name);
            Console.WriteLine("Studentii din grupa: ");

            foreach (Student s in this.SetStudent)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" " + s.Name+ " " + s.Surname + "  ---  " + s.Average+"\n");
            }
        }
     }
public class An
    {
        public int Anul { get; set; }
        public List<Grupa> SetGrupa { get; set; }

        public An()
        {
            SetGrupa = new List<Grupa>();
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Anul: " + this.Anul);
            Console.WriteLine("Grupele din acest an: ");
            foreach (Grupa g in this.SetGrupa)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" " + g.Name);
            }
        }
              }



    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\C#\Tema1\Tema1.txt");

    System.Console.WriteLine("Content Tema1.txt= \n");
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
          Console.WriteLine("\t" + line);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n Close");
    System.Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: How do you read it exactly? Would be better to see your code as well.

Comment: Andrei and Roxana are surnames, yes.

Comment: @John what does your desired output look like?

Comment: So actually you have code here for reading your file. What does not work? Split up the line into fields?

Comment: Year:3  .Has classes :314 ,312.Class 314 has students : X,Y,Z etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Read Text File Containing Data Delimited By Tabs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1028224/c-sharp-read-text-file-containing-data-delimited-by-tabs)

Comment: Well @ThomasKrojer , it doesn't make what i need . Look at my comment and i hope that you will understand

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the .NET `TextFieldParser` for that type of flat file:

```
var studentList = new List<Student>();

var parser = new Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser("<file path>");
parser.SetFieldWidths(4, 4, 12, 8, 2);

while (!parser.EndOfData)
{
     string[] line = parser.ReadFields();

     var student = new Student();
     student.Year = int.Parse(line[0]);
     student.Class = int.Parse(line[1]);
     student.Name = line[2].Trim();
     student.Surname = line[3].Trim();
     student.Average = int.Parse(line[4]);

     studentList.Add(student);
}
```

You just have to setup the field lengths in the `SetFieldWidths` function.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a *vague* one, are you looking for *Linq* like that:

```
// Parsing into objects
var data = System.IO.File
  .ReadLines(@"D:\C#\Tema1\Tema1.txt")
  .Skip(1) //TODO: comment down this line if your file doesn't have a caption
  .Select(line => line.Split('\t'))
  .Select(items => new { // or "new Student() {" if you've designed a Student class
    Year    = int.Parse(items[0]),
    Class   = int.Parse(items[1]),
    Name    = items[2],
    Surname = items[3],
    Average = int.Parse(items[4]), //TODO: Is it Int32 or Double?
  });

...

// combining back: 
String result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, data
  .Select(item => String.Join("\t", 
     item.Year, item.Class, item.Name, item.Surname, item.Average));

Console.Write(result);
```

Comment: I have this break point .At items => new
                {
                    An = int.Parse(items[0]),
                    Grupa= int.Parse(items[1]),
                    Name = items[2],
                    Surname = items[3],
                    Average = int.Parse(items[4]),
                });  "Input string was not in a correct format."

Comment: @John: it seems, that you have to *skip a caption* before reading and parsing the body, see my edit: `.Skip(1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have total control over what you want to do, I advise to create a class for each individual studet.

A rough approach:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{

    class Student
    {
        //Members of class
        public int Year;
        public int Class;
        public string FirstName;
        public string LastName;
        public int Average;

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets a line and creates a student object
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="line">The line to be parsed</param>
        public Student(string line)
        {
            //being parsing

            //split by space
            List<String> unfiltered = new List<string>(line.Split(' '));

            //a list to save filtered data
            List<string> filtred = new List<string>();

            //filter out empty spaces...
            //There exist much smarter ways...but this does the job 
            foreach (string entry in unfiltered)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(entry))
                    filtred.Add(entry);
            }

            //Set variables
            Year = Convert.ToInt32(filtred[0]);
            Class = Convert.ToInt32(filtred[1]);
            FirstName = filtred[2];
            LastName = filtred[3];
            Average = Convert.ToInt32(filtred[4]);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"d:\data.txt");

            //a list to hold students
            List<Student> students = new List<Student>();

            foreach (var line in data)
            {
                //create a new student and add it to list
                students.Add(new Student(line));
            }

            //to test, write all names
            foreach (var student in students)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(student.FirstName + " " + student.LastName + Environment.NewLine);
            }

            //you can calculate average of all students averages!
            int sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < students.Count; i++)
            {
                sum += students[i].Average;
            }

            //print average of all students
            Console.WriteLine("Average mark of all students: " + (sum / students.Count));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have to take all of the informations from my txt, i can't introduce manualy.

Comment: The code I posted reads the text file and creates the student objects. It doesn't introduce manually...But I really cant understand what you mean by introduce manually. Perhaps try the code and see what it does maybe it helps to understand.

Comment: Do you mean you have separate files for groups, students, marks, etc? It is really not clear what you want to do.

Comment: No, i don't have separate files . I have just one file. In my code i have my connections, and i wanted to show you how i made those connections.

Comment: I really can not understand what you exactly want todo. maybe you can try and write it step by step in your question?